Flutter Windows error when installing application, "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b"
When I am trying to install the Flutter Windows application to Windows 10, it gives me an error:

the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b


The 0xc000007b error code is usually caused by corrupt app files or conflicts between 32-bit and 64-bit software and Windows versions, maybe check your dependancy software by repair/reinstall and ensure the correct architecture installation is in place for your hardware/platform.
